# how to design a class with member functions that are promises

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

In node.js, I have been using promises, Q and deferred.
I also have custom objects.

I want to have a custom object that called upon return promises, one for a DO command and one for an UNDO command.

How do I define a member function that is a promise?

Comment: What do you mean by `a member function that is a promise`? Can you elaborate, perhaps with some psuedocode?

Comment: Do you mean a member function that *returns* a promise?

Comment: "member functions that are promises" makes no sense. function == function and promise == promise.

Comment: @Nate yes a member function that returns a promise is what I meant to say

Answer (score 2):

That should be just as simple has have a function return a promise, or in your case two promises in a collection. Sounds like an undoable-function-factory?

I'm unclear about what you mean by command in this case though, I have my suspicions but wouldn't mind you explaining your needs further.

I can speak to an approach we've taken for registering undo/redo operations using promises in MontageJS.

https://github.com/montagejs/montage/blob/master/core/undo-manager.js

In short, we register an undo operation for each undoable method at the time it's invoked, the payload of "what to do to actually perform that undo" operation is stored as a promise to be resolved when we know how to actually undo.

We take the approach that every undoable API is responsible for reporting how to undo itself with some other API which is comparable to some existing systems, but differs from having a unique undo and redo function.

The API:

```
undoManager.register(label, operationPromise)
```

A contrived example undoing an asynchronous operation:

```
addRandomNumber: {
   var deferredUndo,
       self = this;

   this.undoManager.register("Add Random", deferredUndo.promise);

   return this.randomNumberGeneratorService.next().then(function(rand) {
       deferredUndo.resolve(["Add " + rand, self.subtract, self, rand];
       var result = self.total = self.total + number;
       return result
   });
```

}

The jsdocs should have some more information about how we manage undos. if that's of any help.

Hopefully, with more information from you, I can address your specific architecture.

Comment: my node server is a SOAP client. My commands are, at the end of day, SOAP calls. So I will to process a list of commands, i.e. series of SOAP calls, in a transaction nature. Process until one fails, in which case you will undo the commands that succeeded. What I am thinking is having a class for each type of command I will process, add fabric, update fabric, delete fabric. My commands will be an array of these classes, let call them Command objects. I create one, add it to the list. Each Command will have a do and an undo method. THey will both return promises.